# How to log into a Linux virtual machine when its root user is expired and reason being failed to change password

Tags: ubuntu, users

I created a Ubuntu 18.04.6 LTS VM on vSphere. Created a user, test. VM is a 1-year-old machine. Now when I am trying to log in ( through PuTTY), I can't. I checked the logs it says that the "account root has expired" (failed to change password) and the account test has expired (failed to change password)

How can I log in to the VM?

Comment: It is unclear what Unix you installed and how you configured it.  You have tagged your question with the [tag:linux] tag, but you don't mention what distribution you used, nor what release of that distribution.  If account expiration was configured, then I see nothing strange with the behaviour you observe.  You should still be able to start the VM in single user mode though.

Comment: @Kusalananda it's Ubuntu 18.04.6 LTS.  I did not set any expiration policy while configuring the VM.I had to put a Linux tag as it was not accepting the unix tag while I was posting the question.

Comment: Hello and welcome to unix.se. A thing to try: `1) stop the vm`. `2) edit its disk` (ie: mount it on another vm where) so that you can : `2A`) copy /etc/passwd and /etc/shadow (and also their equivalent under /etc/security/) as "theirname-old", `2B`) edit the 2nd field of /etc/shadow for the root user, and clear that 2nd field (ie, it will go from `root:somethingehere:....` to `root::....`), then `3) reboot as single user` (or as usual?), log in as root and no passxord (or just press enter when prompter for it), and the first thing you do is :  `passwd root`, to create & put a new one in place.